# Nodejs Docker container immediately stop after run for express module not found

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker

I have searched all the answers related to this on stackoverflow but none seems to solve my issue. I was following this link to dockerize my nodejs-mysql app:

https://github.com/varunon9/getting-started-docker-mysql-nodejs#launching-nodejs-app-in-a-container

When I come to step-8 and do `docker ps` the container is not showing. I have checked the logs and it says "Error: Cannot find module 'express'". My run command is:

```
docker run  -t -d \
--publish 7000:7000 \
--link testmysqlservice:db \
--name=test-nodejs-microservice patient-nodejs
```

[Docker Error Log shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SfCq.png)

[After step-8 the sql service seems to get stuck or running not sure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bLJI.png)

> package.json file

```
{
  "name": "paloit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "arraylist": "^0.1.0",
    "avl": "^1.4.4",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
    "ejs": "^3.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "hashmap": "^2.4.0",
    "hashtable": "git+https://github.com/fabrice102/node-hashtable.git",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jsdom": "^15.2.1",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "multimap": "^1.1.0",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "sort-map": "^1.0.0",
    "sorted-map": "^0.1.8",
    "yargs": "^15.0.2"
  }
}
```

> Docker file for Mysql

### Pull the mysql:5.7 image

```
FROM mysql:5.7

## The maintainer name and email
LABEL gaga maga <gagad@gmail.com>

# database = test and password for root = password
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=patientdb \
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password

# when container will be started, we'll have `test` database created with this schema
COPY ./patientschem_patient.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

> Dockerfile for Nodejs

```
# Use Node v8 as the base image.
FROM node:8

# create and set app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 7000
# Run app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

> Part of server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');

const request = require('request');
const argv = require('yargs').argv;

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    
       ........
    request(url, function(error, response, body, next) {
        var illness = JSON.parse(body)
        var ill = illness._embedded.illnesses
        //var link = _links.self        
        
       res.render(....);
    });

});


function getConnection(){
    return mysql.createConnection(
        {
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            password: 'password',
            database: 'patientschem'
        }

    )

}


app.post('/displayhospital', (req, res) => {
    console.log("trying to get form data");
    .......
    const queryString = "INSERT INTO patient (e, d, p) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE d = VALUES(dl), p = VALUES(pl)"

});
    

   

const server = app.listen(7000, () => {
    console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
  });
```

I have two ejs files - index and result

Comment: is the container visible to you once you run build?

run the following command : docker images

Comment: navigate inside the docker image patient-node.js 
using the follwing command
docker run -it <image-id> sh

get the image-id from the docker images command output above

Comment: i tried building and running the docker image myself and was able to run successfully...
lets debug your implementation now..

The ran the following commands :
```
docker build -t test-nodejs .
docker images
docker run  -t -d --publish 7000:7000  test-nodejs
```

Comment: From the error logs, it appears to be an issue where the dependencies for nodejs to run have not been installed properly. worth looking into the `docker build` logs.

Comment: Another issue that you will face is the db connection url . `localhost` will refer to node app container at runtime which is wrong. Search for docker network and how to add containers on it.

Comment: @shubham when I do ```docker images``` both the container are visible to me (patient-nodejs and patient-mysql).
When i do "docker run -it 28b66d3509b5 sh" it gives a # in next line and seems it went inside that image. not sure what does that mean.

I tried the _3_debug_commands_ you provided. It runs successfully even for me. but just after the last command if you do ```docker ps``` you won't see that container ID anymore. which means it is **exiting while it should be running**.

Comment: @leopal https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql it should be localhost. The npm site itself is using localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: 
The problem was in my package.json indeed. I was missing express. Also arraylist was with small 'a' and in my server.js it was require('Arraylist') which created the conflict. 
But surprisingly when I was running the app without docker it was running successfully.
Thank u.